# resilience4j annotations not working on chlid class

Tags: spring-boot, aop, resilience4j

I am using resilience4j with SpringBoot. I see that the resilience4j annotations work only if they are placed in the class which throws the exception. If the class is extended by another class & the parent class has the annotation then the retries do not work.

Resilience4j Config

```
resilience4j.retry: 
  instances:       
    service: 
      maxRetryAttempts: 5
      waitDuration: 1000
      retryException: 
        - com.common.exception.RetriableException
```

Parent Class

```java
@Retry(name = "service")
@Component
public class httpClient extends client{

  // This method is invoked from outside
  public HttpResponse<T> getResponse(
      String url, Class<T> responseType) {
    return super.getResponse(url, requestEntity, responseType);
  }
}
```

Child Class

```java
@Retry(name = "service") // Without this line, the retries don't work, even though it is present in the parent class
@Component
public class client{

  public HttpResponse<T> getResponse(
      String url, Class<T> responseType) {
    //Impl which throws RetriableException
  }
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour ? Can you let me know if I am missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used Resilience4j before, but what I can tell you about Java annotations in general is:

- An overridden method in a subclass **never** inherits annotations from the original parent class method.
- In a class implementing an interface an implementing method **never** inherits annotations from the corresponding interface method.
- A classes implementing an interface **never** inherits annotations from the interface itself.
- An interface extending another interface also **never** inherits any type or method level annotations.
- By default not even a subclass inherits annotations from its parent class.
- There is a single exception to this "annotations are never inherited" rule: A type level annotation (something like `@Foo class Base`, can also be abstract) ***can*** be inherited by a subclass (something like `class Sub extends Base`) ***if and only if*** the annotation class itself carries the meta annotation [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

Having said that and looking at the [`@Retry`](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/650e37bb85aa2b809214bfc1c3c28a31a43df9cf/resilience4j-annotations/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/retry/annotation/Retry.java#L26) annotation, you will notice that there is no `@Inherited` annotation there, so it also cannot work in your case.

If there is another way (e.g. via reflection) to get this done in Resilience4j, I do not know because, as I said, I never used it before.